# Find the greatest integer $k$ for which $1991^k$ divides $1990^{{1991}^{1992}}+1992^{{1991}^{1990}}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Find the greatest integer $k$ for which $1991^k$ divides $$1990^{{1991}^{1992}}+1992^{{1991}^{1990}}$$

It is easy to see that $k \geq 1$ as $1990 \equiv -1$ and $1992 \equiv 1 \pmod{1991}$
Also, I thought that perhaps as $1991$ is the product of two distinct primes, it would be worth looking at small values of $(pq)^k||(pq-1)^{{pq}^{pq+1}}+(pq+1)^{{pq}^{pq-1}}$ for primes $p$ and $q$. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: is it $1990^{\left( 1991^{1992} \right)}$ or $\left( 1990^{1991} \right)^{1992}$

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the former. But I'm not certain. This was the problem as I found it. I think it's from an IMO shortlist.

Comment: The existing answers show $k$ can be at least $1991$. I haven't followed the link to the detail of the "Lifting the Exponent Lemma", but do we know there is no greater value for $k$?

Comment: @DanZimm by convention, $ a^{b^c} $ means $a^{(b^c)}$ not $(a^b)^c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I shall prove a more general result: Let $n>1$ be an odd positive integer. Then $n^n \|[(n-1)^{n^{n+1}}+(n+1)^{n^{n-1}}]$.

**Proof:** 
\begin{align}
(n-1)^{n^2}+(n+1)=\sum_{i=0}^{n^2}{\binom{n^2}{i}(-1)^{n^2-i}n^i}+(n+1) & \equiv \binom{n^2}{1}n-1+(n+1) \pmod{n^2}\\
& \equiv n \pmod{n^2}
\end{align}

Now applying [Lifting the Exponent Lemma](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/LTE.pdf) on each prime factor of $n$, we have $n^n \|[(n-1)^{n^{n+1}}+(n+1)^{n^{n-1}}]$.

For your special case, $k=1991$.

Comment: (+1) For *Lifting the exponent lemma*. This seems pretty interesting. It can be used in Olympiad without mentioning the proof right?

Comment: @Inceptio yes. In this case, one would write $n=\prod_{i=1}^{m}{p_i^{a_i}}$, then $v_{p_i}((n-1)^{n^{n+1}}+(n+1)^{n^{n-1}}) =v_{p_i}((n-1)^{n^2}+(n+1))+v_{p_i}(n^{n-1}) =v_{p_i}(n^n)$

Comment: I'm guessing $v_p(x^n+y^n)=v_p(x+y)+v_p(n)$ has been used here.

Comment: @Inceptio Indeed. Of course that requires the exponent to be odd, which is indeed the case here.

Comment: The "lifting the exponent lemma" link is dead.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a=1991$, and let $$b=(a-1)^{ a^{a+1} } + (a+1)^{ a^{a-1} }$$

The goal is to compute $\nu_{a}(b)$. To do so, we will evaluate $b$ modulo $a^{a+1}$.

Applying binomial expansions, $$b\equiv (-1)^{a^{a+1}} + 1 + a^{a-1} a\mod{a^{a+1}}$$ (because all the higher order terms vanish).

Since $a^{a+1}$ is odd, this simplifies to $$b \equiv a^a\mod{a^{a+1}}$$
Therefore, $\nu_{a}(b)=a$. To rephrase in the terminology of your question, $k=1991$.

Comment: Your wrote: "because all the higher order terms vanish". Do you have a proof of that?